# GCM android chat application work on one emulator but not on the other

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I create an android chat application using GCM (Google cloud messaging).

i use Genymotion Emulator to execute the app. i figured out that nexus 6 can send and receive messages to/from nexus7, but Nexus 7 cannot receive messages sent by nexus6. this image below demonstrate the problem :

[image]

why is this happening ?

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/11/android-chat-application-using-gcm-mysql.html)

Comment: Event though GCM is based on top of XMPP, it was never meant to be used for a chat application. GCM message delivery is controlled by multiple configurable options like priority and ttl.  I would advise using services like telegram or layer

Comment: but i have read that a lot of well-known application are using GCM, so it should be a good choice to work with GCM

Comment: you are replying in transport which is used by a lot of other apps as well. It is efficient for message delivery but it is not your own highway. Its a shared expressway. Delivery guarantee, delivery receipts are not possible using GCM Http CCS servers, you get that with XMPP server though. Also message coming on NEXUS 6 and not NEXUS 7 has nothing to do with gcm. Its something else. Are both the emulators running Google APIs image ?

Comment: yes I installed Google Play Services and updated all proposed updates i have Google Play Services (8.7.03)